# Flexigrid thead and tbody mismatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexigrid

I am using flexigrid in my application,its rendering properly,but when am about to drag any column to increase the length of the column,tbody is not in sync with the thead. See the below image for reference
[image: see the below image for reference]

Please help to how to make the tbody is in sync with thead.
Thanks.
Update:I am expecting the column to be resized,instead the previous column is being resized. i.e. the header for the column works perfectly, but the corresponding column cells width is not changing, and the column cells one column to the left change to match the header of the actual column being changed.i.e. if you are dragging nth header ,tbody of (n-1)th is getting changed.

Comment: Post your code please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occurring when we are having more no. of div's inside the td.
It will be resolved by changing the below lines of code in `flexigrid.js`.

Original Line of Code.

```
$('td:visible div:eq(' + n + ')', this).css('width',nw);
```

Need to replace with.

```
$('td:visible:eq(' + (n) + ') div:eq(0)',this).css('width',nw);
```